# How can I transform one end of a cylindrical extrusion to create a cone or needle-like structure?

Tags: mesh, transforms

I have a mesh with a cylindrical extrusion and I would like to make this extrusion appear like a cone or needle.  I have tried scaling the end faces/edges/verts of the cylinder, but this scales the entire mesh.  I do not want to scale the entire mesh.

Before:

```
+================+
|                |
|                +=============================+
|                                              |
|                           cylinder           |         
|                                              |
|    (mesh)      +=============================+
|                |
+================+
```

Desired result:

```
+================+
|                |
|                +=============+
|                               ========+                
|                   needle/cone          ======             
|                               ========+              
|    (mesh)      +=============+
|                |
+================+
```

Yes, I'm in Edit Mode and, yes, pivot center is set to Median Point.

[Here's a screencast of what is happening](http://screencast.com/t/ATt40tLXL).

Comment: +1 for the original example images :) You can also take a [screenshot](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Vitals/Screenshots) or [screencast](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Vitals/Screencasts) with blender, might be faster..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are either in Object Mode or have the whole mesh selected.

Make sure that you are in Edit Mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). In the header of the 3D View:

[image: Edit Mode selection]

Then press <kbd>A</kbd> repeatedly until nothing is selected. Then use border select (<kbd>B</kbd>) for example to select the right most vertices:

[image: Selection]

Then scale them down. It might be that you have to change your pivot point to Median Point.
Again in the 3D View header:

[image: Median Point selection]

You also have to make sure that proportional editing is off (<kbd>O</kbd>) (header again).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I gave your recommendations a shot, but still having issues.  See the screencast in my updated question.

Comment: I'm selecting the outermost verts and then pressing <kbd>S</kbd> to scale.

Comment: I updated my answer. You have proportional editing on.

Comment: That was it.  Proportional editing was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to, when the points at the right are selected, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> to merge the points together.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain?

Comment: @WChargin I didn't downvote this, but It doesn't answer the question "How to scale down only part of a mesh".

Comment: The question is how to turn it into a cone shaped structure. merging the vertices does that.